# Сделать в webpack, alias как в реакте

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

В реакте использую такой конфиг для обрезания путей:

```
{
"compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "src"
},
"include": ["src"]
```

}

Как такое повторить в WebPack?

Пока получается только так:

```
    resolve: {
    alias: {
        components: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/components'),
        utils: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/components/utils'),
    }
},
```

Можно ли это как-то упростить, как в первом варианте, например?

Answer (score 1):

Посмотрите на пример [отсюда](https://dev.to/georgedoescode/simplify-your-imports-with-webpack-aliases-59f)

Чтобы записать

```
import MyComponent from '../../../../components/MyComponent.js'
```

в такой форме

```
import MyComponent from 'Components/MyComponent.js'
```

нужно прописать в конфиге

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  // configuration options for how webpack resolves modules
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      // add as many aliases as you like! 
      Components: path.resolve(__dirname, 'path/to/your/components/dir') 
    }
  }
  // ... rest of your config
}
```

Comment: Да, только приходится каждую папку описывать. Так и сделал. На реакте, как-то проще вышло. Две строчки.

Comment: а так попробовать  scr: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src'), components: path.resolve(scr, 'components'),

Comment: Не с scr, не с this.scr. не работает. Ладно, запишу, влпоть до папки) Спасибо.